# Remove div elements from HTML string

Tags: jquery

I have HTML like this in a string:

```
<div style="" class="">
    <div style="" class="">
        <h1>test</h1>
        <p>
            text
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I use jQuery to remove the `<div>`'s and just keep the inner HTML:

```
<h1>test</h1>
<p>
    text
</p>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "keep"? Is there another element you want them appended to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `.unwrap();`

from the docs:

> **Description:** Remove the parents of the set of matched elements from the DOM, leaving the matched elements in their place.

```js
$('p, h1').unwrap().unwrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="" class="">
    <div style="" class="">
        <h1>test</h1>
        <p>
            text
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is to use [`unwrap`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) method like this:

```
$('div').contents().unwrap('div');
```

Check the demo below.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
    $('div').contents().unwrap('div');
});
```

```css
div {
    border: 1px red solid;
    padding: 10px;
}
div div {
    border-color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="" class="">
    <div style="" class="">
        <h1>test</h1>
        <p>
            text <button>Remove div's</div>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```